# Storing files in some sd card in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, file-io, windows-phone

I am writing a Windows Phone 8.1 app. I have seen examples of file handling and all interface with Local Storage only. This means that these files can be accessed only when the app is running(This is what I perceive and I can be wrong in this). Is there any way that an app can store a file in some other location like on the SD card which the user can explicitly access without running the app. It would be great help if you could direct me to some code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `Removeable Storage` capability and specify at least one `File Type Association` in the package manifest. (You'll get access denied errors if you don't.)

You can then do things like this, which will display how many files, of a supported type, are in the root of the SD card.

```
// Get the first child folder, which represents the SD card.
var card = (await externalDevices.GetFoldersAsync()).FirstOrDefault();

if (card != null)
{
    // An SD card is present
    var files = await card.GetFilesAsync();

    new MessageDialog(files.Count().ToString()).ShowAsync();
}
else
{
    // No SD card is present
}
```

The above just shows reading a file count but you can work with the SD card like any other `StorageFolder`.